# GLMM, introducing weight variable changes Pseudo-R^2 but not AIC

Tags: r, aic, glmm

Here is a reproducible example using R, where I noticed that adding a uniform weight value to a glmm,the AIC of models stay the same but Pseudo R^2 gets reduced a lot. Why?

```
require(lme4)
require(MuMIn)

data<-sleepstudy #Load data.
weight<-rep(470,180) #I create a uniform variable that will be the weight.
newdata<-cbind(sleepstudy,weight)

m1<-lmer(data=newdata,formula=Reaction~Days+(1|Subject)) # Run normal model without weights
m2<-lmer(data=newdata,formula=Reaction~(1|Subject)) # Run null model without weights

anova(m1,m2) #Compare models and check AIC.

r.squaredGLMM(m1) #Check Pseudo R^2
r.squaredGLMM(m2)


m3<-lmer(data=newdata,formula=Reaction~Days+(1|Subject),weights=weight) #Run models with weights.
m4<-lmer(data=newdata,formula=Reaction~(1|Subject),weights=weight)

anova(m3,m4)

r.squaredGLMM(m3)
r.squaredGLMM(m4)
```

When I add weights (e.g. I assume there is a maximum level of "Reaction"), AIC of the models stay invariable BUT R^2 goes down abruptly. The same happens with a dataset I have. I run the models using a binomial distribution (dependent variable is a proportion) and when adding weights, R^2 is destroyed.
Does anybody know why this happens and/or how to overcome this issue (i.e understand why my data is now not explaining almost variance of the dependent variable)?

Comment: Why should you add uniform weight value to a glmm ? What is the link between the AIC of models  and Pseudo R^2 .

Comment: As far as I know: when fitting a binomial model with proportional data, "weights" tell the model what is the maximum value that your data can get (e.g. maximum number of cavities that can be occupied, so it could be uniform). The model gives you an error if you don`t give it the weights. AIC tells you what model is best (best fitted considering parsimony). Pseudo-R^2 tells you what model explains more variance of your data, so it is also a measure of goodness of fit.

Comment: what is your objective and data ? is it possible that you post your output ?

Comment: A layman's answer shall be that AIC modelling and pseudo - R squared modelling have different assumptions . Perhaps, an understanding of convergence and divergence could be useful.

Comment: I run the models using a binomial distribution (dependent variable is a proportion) and when adding weights, R^2 is destroyed.  You may please note that the proportion can not be considered as binomial variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation in MuMin cannot be used if you have weights in your model.

`help("lmer")` says:

> **weights:**  an optional vector of ‘prior weights’ to be used in the fitting process. Should be NULL or a numeric vector. Prior weights are
>   not normalized or standardized in any way. In particular, the diagonal
>   of the residual covariance matrix is the squared residual standard
>   deviation parameter sigma times the vector of inverse weights.
>   Therefore, if the weights have relatively large magnitudes, then in
>   order to compensate, the sigma parameter will also need to have a
>   relatively large magnitude.

The calculation of the pseudo-R² uses the residual variance as part of a sum in the denominator (see the documentation which gives the equation). This is calculated as sigma² and the scaling by the weights is not considered:

```
r.squaredGLMM(m3) 
#        R2m         R2c 
#0.002003416 0.005041047 
var(as.vector(model.matrix(m3) %*% lme4::fixef(m3))) / 
 (attr(lme4::VarCorr(m3), "sc")^2 + 
  var(as.vector(model.matrix(m3) %*% lme4::fixef(m3))) + 
  c(lme4::VarCorr(m3)$Subject))
#[1] 0.002003416

attr(lme4::VarCorr(m1), "sc")^2
#[1] 960.4566
attr(lme4::VarCorr(m3), "sc")^2 / 470 #scaling factor for your equal weights is 470
#[1] 960.4566
```

You'll need to create your own implementation for lme4 models with weights or/and ask the MuMiN maintainer to modify theirs.